# How to reshape a variable to wide in my dataset?

Tags: stata

I am trying to `reshape` a variable to wide but not getting proper way to do so.

I have the day wise count dataset for each `SSUID` and i would like to reshape the day to wide to show the count for each `SSUID` in aggregate.

Dataset:

```
ssuid   day count
1226    1   3
1226    2   7
1226    3   5
1226    4   7
1226    5   7
1226    6   6
1227    1   3
1227    2   6
1227    3   7
1227    4   4
1228    1   4
1228    2   4
1228    3   6
1228    4   7
1228    5   5
1229    1   3
1229    2   6
1229    3   6
1229    4   6
1229    5   5
```

I tried some code but getting the error:

> count variable not constant within SSUID variable

My code:

```
reshape wide day, i(ssuid) j(count)
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
ssuid   day1   day2   day3   day4   day5   day6  
 1226      3      7      5      7      7      6  
 1227      3      6      7      4      .      .  
 1228      4      4      6      7      5      .  
 1229      3      6      6      6      5      .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
clear

input ssuid day count
1226    1   3
1226    2   7
1226    3   5
1226    4   7
1226    5   7
1226    6   6
1227    1   3
1227    2   6
1227    3   7
1227    4   4
1228    1   4
1228    2   4
1228    3   6
1228    4   7
1228    5   5
1229    1   3
1229    2   6
1229    3   6
1229    4   6
1229    5   5
end

reshape wide count, i(ssuid) j(day)
rename count# day#
```

```
list

     +-------------------------------------------------+
     | ssuid   day1   day2   day3   day4   day5   day6 |
     |-------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1226      3      7      5      7      7      6 |
  2. |  1227      3      6      7      4      .      . |
  3. |  1228      4      4      6      7      5      . |
  4. |  1229      3      6      6      6      5      . |
     +-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much...i was also performed this reshape but didn't  recognised the output correctly. Thanks.